# Selenium IE Webdriver + Proxy: Certificate Warning

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, certificate, selenium-webdriver

Everytime, when I am using a Proxy to filter http Request before testing a site in IE I get a little Pop-up on the buttom of the screen saying: 
"Internet Explorer blocked this website from displaying content with security certificate errors"
I have to tell IE to display the content before the tests can continue. How can I disable this warning?
I already tried disableing every security warning in IE I could find in the options menu but nothing worked so far.
I also tried adding this to my code, which didn't work either:

```
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);  
    capabilities.setCapability(
            InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
            true);
```

Please help me out here!

Answer (score 0):

This is a time synchronization issue. Kindly synchronize your synchronize my PC time with [time.windows.com](http://time.windows.com)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Besides the Warning is only displayed when the webdriver opens the site. I don't get the warning, when I'm navigating there manually, so it's probably not the time. But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove,

> capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
>   true);

and uncheck `enable protected mode` for all the 4 zones from

**Internet options > security**

Note: By default **'Untrusted connection | SSL certificate'** will be disabled in Selenium 2.35; not sure about IE. Try to remove and add both the lines mentioned above.

Comment: No, unfortunately that did not help!